# joining non-spatial pollution model (csv file) to Qgis

Tags: qgis, vector, modelling, environmental-monitoring

I have csv file with concentration data but without coordinates. 
Start of pollution concentration connect with that one point on map.

Is there any chance ?

[image]
[image]

Start of pollution concentration connect with that one point on map. Is there any chance ? 
[image]

I am using QGIS and Rstudio.

Answer (score 1):

You will need some reference from the CSV file to a spatial table to map it. All you seem to have is a id and a pollutant value. If Rstudio made the concentration contour it might be able to export a local reference system for each cell in the raster map. Another go would be to georeference your concentration contour map in QGIS. Then you can use it as a normal raster layer in QGIS.

Comment: the first numbers seems to be distance from point source in [m]. If i make points 50m - 100m - 150m... and than try to connect ID from csv with point ID.
But it will be only on X axis and in circle...

Comment: We can't guess your data, you have to be as specific as possible about what you have and know if you want helpful answers.

Comment: Rstudio writte conc.csv file with 9901 observation of 1 variable. Without spatial data. I guess its counts concentration each meter(first column) on X axis. And i dont know how to connect it with Qgis. 
You wanna see Rcode ?